# How can I make this simple program return without closing?

Tags: c++, c++14

I started trying to learn C++ tonight and I'm just messing around in an IDE right now. How can I make this simple program not close the program until you guess the correct number (5, 6, or 7)?

As it stands it will take one input, then say press any key to close, instead of allowing me to keep guessing.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int favorite_number;

    std::cout << "Enter your favorite number between 1 and 100: ";
    std::cin >> favorite_number;

        if(favorite_number == 5 || favorite_number == 6 || favorite_number == 7)
        {
        std::cout << "Amazing!! That's my favorite number too!";
        }

    std::cout << "Nice try, but that's not my favorite number" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will need to use loops. Please read a programming topic on loops and I am sure you will be able to manage your problem. If you still have problems, then edit/update your question.

Comment: try a while loop instead. have a look on that : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_while_loop.htm

Comment: Got it! Thanks just needed a point in the right direction, did while(!completed) then set completed to true on correct guess.

Comment: @Tman OK, then provide an answer yourself or close your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks got it figured out!

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int favorite_number;
    bool completed = false;

    while(completed == false)
    {
    std::cout << "Enter your favorite number between 1 and 100: ";
    std::cin >> favorite_number;

        if(favorite_number == 5 || favorite_number == 6 || favorite_number == 7)
        {
        std::cout << "Amazing!! That's my favorite number too!";
        completed = true;
        return 0;
        }
        else
             std::cout << "Nice try, but that's not my favorite number" << std::endl;

        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you guess one of the favourite numbers you are still printing the "nice try" message. are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Thanks didn't notice that! I just updated it and noticed i had "completed" assigned to an integer instead of bool as well.

Comment: Also true! Just edited it again, wow there's so many things to take into consideration, i guess i don't need that return 0; at the bottom either?

Comment: @Tman You need a return 0, because your main function is of type int, so it has to return an integer value. 0 is like EXIT_SUCCESS ... so you say that your program exited successfully.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName will it ever reach that second return though? Since it will be permanently stuck in the while loop until the variable "completed" becomes true. At that point that if() statement has its own return 0; inside the loop?

Comment: @Tman It is better you remove the inner return 0 and leave the one at the end.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName please don't edit posts in a way that changes the code flow.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName I did read the comments, and you still shouldn't, unless explicitly asked to by the author.

Comment: `completed` is redundant, since you `return` before ever testing its value. You could get rid of it and change the loop to be `while(true)`

Answer (score 1):

I am glad you found a solution! Furthermore, take a look over this code:

```
int main() 
{
    int favorite_number;

    while(1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your favorite number between 1 and 100: ";
        std::cin >> favorite_number;

        if(5 == favorite_number || 6 == favorite_number || 7 == favorite_number)
        {
            std::cout << "Amazing!! That's my favorite number too!";
            return 0;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Nice try, but that's not my favorite number" << std::endl;

    }
}
```

You can make the loop infinite without using that bool completed. This way it will run as long as the number inserted is different from one of the favorite numbers. Also, the last return in your code is extra. Changing the order inside `if(5 == favorite_number)`, for example, is considered a good practice because you might write by mistake `favorite_number = 5` (assignment), which is valid and this way you will have a bug harder to find.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm trying to understand that, is it because the following if() statement will return a "true" value when it matches the correct number?

What would happen to that code if there was a nested if() statement under that original if(), would I need to bring back the boolean?

Comment: @Tman when if condition is true, after printing "Amazing!! That's my favorite number too!" you have a return statement. This return will will end main() function(notice that main has an int as return type and the return statement from your if returns 0). I am bad at explaining, more info and more examples can be found here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return